# class level variables will be shared by all servlet requests?

Tags: java, servlets, struct

```
public class A {
protected Connection con = null;
public void openDbConnection() throws CpiSystemException {
        try {
            if (con == null || con.isClosed()) {
                con = CpiDataSource.getNonTxConnection();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            new CpiSystemException("SQLException caused by con.isClosed(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
public class B extends A {
private Connection con;
// if two servlets requests came to execute below method, both will use same connection object or will create different objects?
public void executeQuery(){
openDbConnection();
con.prepareStatement(SELECT_CUST_PILN_PREF_BY_CRTN_USER_ID);
}
}
public class C extends HttpServlet {
B b = null;
init(){
}
doget(request, response){
b = new B();
b.executeQuery();
}
}
```

**My Doubt is:**
For each servlet request one connection object will be created , or same connection object for all servlet requests (we know that each servlet request it will create thread)

Comment: You must read this article http://yiyujia.blogspot.in/2011/12/on-my-post-about-java-class-loader-i.html

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime of the `con` instance variables depends on the lifetime of the instances of `A` and `B`.  It is not possible to say *anything* about whether (or not) there will be one `con` instance per servlet without information about how the `A` and `B` instances are created and used.

However, there is clearly a bug in your code.  You have to distinct declarations of `con` with the declaration in `B` shadowing the declaration in `A`.  When you call `openDbConnection()` it will assign a value to `A.con` ... but when you call `executeQuery()` the code refers to `B.con` which will still be `null`.  This might be the cause of your "doubts".

Answer (score 0):

I agree with  @Stephen C, in the sense that your code has a bug.
But leaving that aside, I think your statement,

```
b = new B();
```

makes the difference here. Every time a new instance of B will be created which has its own `con` object. So yes, each new request will create a new object and thereby a new connection.